# Does Dragon Soul pierce Resist All?

Tags: dnd-4e, sorcerer, damage-resistance

The Sorcerer feature Dragon Soul allows you to pierce resistances of which you are resistant. I have a lightning resistance. Do I *also* pierce Resist All when I attack with lightning spells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the Sorcerers features that allow the mechanic you describe say something along the lines of:

> Your arcane powers ignore any target's resistance to **that damage
>   type** up to the value of your resistance.
>   (Emphasis mine)

So in your case, you would only ignore lightening resistance up to your lightening resistance amount. Untyped resistances would be unaffected this feature.